# How to add custom new section(tab) in Product form in magento 2

Tags: backend, magento2.3.1, adminform, tabs

How to add a new custom section in Product form in Magento 2 ?

I just want to add this new section as a new tab like content, configuration, etc...

Please refer to the attachment.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your module you have to create:

- ui_component: view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 - Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 - See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <htmlContent name="custom" sortOrder="10">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="wrapper" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Content</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <wrapper>
                <canShow>true</canShow>
                <componentType>fieldset</componentType>
            </wrapper>
        </settings>
        <block name="custom.block" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Custom" template="Vendor_Module::product/custom.phtml"/>
    </htmlContent>
</form>
```

- Custom Block: Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Custom.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product;

/**
 * Class Custom
 *  * @package Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product;
 */
class Custom extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    public function customContent()
    {
        return 'custom content from block';
    }
}
```

- phtml: Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/product/custom.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var $block \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Custom */
?>

<h1>custom content</h1>
<div>
    <?= $block->customContent()?>
</div>
```

And this is the final result:
[image]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: To change order just edit sortOrder value: ```<htmlContent name="custom" sortOrder="10">```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will check and let you know

Comment: Can you please tell me... how to add dynamic rows instead of custom content

Answer (score 0):

You can Add new group from:

> Stores -> Attributes -> Attribute Set

Click on Your attribute set

In the Groups Click **Add New** . It will create a New Group.

If you want to put it below Content Group, You can drag it using mouse.

[image]

In the Screen Shot, I created a **Test Group**

Comment: Hi @Pawan, thanks for the response. I don't want to show any custom attributes there. It is the best way to show our custom attributes. But I need to show custom content inside the tab